# How to give Id to model in razor pages to use in jquery script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

inside my view I want to give an Id to child model name and use it in my script file following is my code.

**in the View**

```
    Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TOURNAMENTS_D.GetType().Name, new {id = "Test"});
```

**in the script file**

```
var a = $("#Test").val();
alert($("#Test").val());
```

however when I debug my code  value is undefined

am I doing wrong? I'm a former winforms developer thus new to these concepts I might be missing things..

thanks in advance

Comment: The `#Test` element should exist given the HTML helper you used. Check the actual HTML output to ensure it's rendered as you expect, and also check the console for errors.

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TOURNAMENTS_D, new { id = "Test" })` should work. The value may be undefined only if the hidden field not rendered.

Comment: what generated is <input id="Title" name="Title" type="hidden" value="{ id = Child }" />

Comment: Using `GetType().Name` in your expression makes no sense. What are you actually trying to generate the input for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest way is inspect your element in the browser. It will show the id that is generated for the hidden field.

Also you should use @id to set the id of the input in razor

Comment: You do nit need `@id` - the `@` is only required for reserved keywords (e.g. `@class = `

Comment: adding the add worked!

<input id="Test" name="TOURNAMENTS_D" type="hidden" value="" />
and how do I add value?

Comment: did not know it was reserved, alternatively you can set @data_id = "Test" and in jquery $('input[data-id="Test"]').val();

Comment: to add value use @Value (use capital letters)

Comment: Never ever set the value attribute (unless you want to screw up model binding). You set the value of the property in the GET method before you send it to the view